# How to disable SSL in IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

How to disable HTTPS requirement when using Discovery in IdentityServer4?
I'm working on local server and when I use a self-signed certificate (with openssl) can not trust to it and when I use http an error returns: Https required.

Answer (score 2):

In your project with protected API or client project's `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method in Startup.cs:

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => {
       .
       .
       .
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```

or

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
       .
       .
       .
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```